# Help with 2D forward kinematics

Tags: forward-kinematics

I have been trying to find the HTM of a 2-DOF arm in 2D by finding the rotation matrices and displacement vectors by hand rather than use DH parameters to better understand them. I have followed the steps in this [video](https://tinyurl.com/y8qoxgmw) to find the rotation matrices by finding the rotation when the joint angle is 0, and multiplying with the 2x2 rotation matrix around the z-axis.

However, when I solve for the HTM with theta1 = 90 degrees in python, I get a displacement vector of 0,0. I am wondering if the method I'm using to find the R0-1 is correct, especially since frame 1 is offset from frame 0. My steps are listed below:

[image]

a1 and a2 are the link lengths, and theta1 and theta2 are the joint positions, shown starting at 0.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: It looks like your two z axes should point in the opposite direction (right hand rule).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track.

Prof. B.K.P. Horn at the MIT AI lab wrote [this paper](https://people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/AIWP/AI_WP_099.pdf) to analyze this problem almost 50 years ago - at a time when there weren't any robotics texts available.  He goes through the problem slowly and step-by-step in a "classical" fashion.

The location of the first actuator is given by:

> $x_1 = a_1\cos\theta_1$
>
> $y_1 = a_1\sin\theta_1$

The location of the arm tip is:

> $x_2 = a_1\cos\theta_1 + a_2\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)$
>
> $y_2 = a_1\sin\theta_1 + a_2\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)$

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for, but if not I think you will find some guidance in Prof. Horn's paper.  He also solves the torque problem using Lagrangians and goes through that step-by-step.  If you have any other questions, you might email him.  After 50 years, he is still at MIT and writes back!

Comment: *The location of the first actuator is given by* this is the location of the second motor.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want DH, then why bother at all with rotation matrices. For this simple case, you can do it by hand much simpler than dealing with the rotation matrices.
[image]